# add text/numbers in string builder based on length of string builder

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio

I wanted to add the numbers (1,2,3) in my string builder before displaying.
If the string builder contains 2- it should have output like this 1) Line text 2) line text and so on

```
StringBuilder abc = new StringBuilder();
abc.Append("Hi.");
Fun(2, abc);
void Fun(int i, StringBuilder abc)
{
    if (i>0)
    abc.Append("its me.");
}
```

// Add some code here to check like if(abc.length>0) // we need to append 1,2,3... to the lines in abc
    Console.WriteLine(abc.ToString());

i need the output like

> 1)Hi. 2) its me.

Comment: i am not familiar much with C#... i mostly work in python so posted the question

Answer (score 3):

You can encapsulate logic in different class and use StringBuilder under the hood.

```
public class ExtendedStringBuilder
{
    private StringBuilder _sb;
    private int _callNumber;
    public ExtendedStringBuilder()
    {
        _sb = new StringBuilder();
        _callNumber = 0;
    }

    public void Append(string nextString)
    {
        _sb.AppendFormat("{0} {1}", ++_callNumber, nextString);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

In this case you do not need to store int value. This is sample:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var esb = new ExtendedStringBuilder();

    esb.Append("Hi.");
    esb.Append("its me.");
    Console.WriteLine(esb.ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be incredibly hard to do it with `StringBuilder` as index parsing will be ridiculously difficult. I've used `List<string>` to achieve the same.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("Hi");
list.Add("Its me!");

string s = String.Join(" ", list.Select(x => (list.IndexOf(x) + 1).ToString() + ")" + x));

Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Which gives the output as

> 1)Hi 2)Its me!

Comment: appreciate your help... i have to use the stringbuilder

Comment: Can I ask why, you would be just shooting yourself in the foot by using `StringBuilder`. I don't know the context but you can do something like this to convert your `StringBuilder` to `List<string>` using 
`sb.ToString().Split(' ').ToList();`

Comment: You can't use `select` with `StringBuilder` because it is not an `Enumerable`. The `Select` is an extension method is only available for `Enumerable` types. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using *Linq*, put all the items (`"Hi."`, `"its me."`) and get rid of `StringBuilder`:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ... 

  // Or List<string> 
  string[] items = new string[] {
    "Hi.",
    "its me."
  };

  string result = string.Join(" ", items
    .Select((item, index) => $"{index + 1}){item}"));
```

Your code *modified* (`List<string>` instead of `StringBuilder`)

```
  List<string> abc = new List<string>(); // List<string>, not StringBuider

  abc.Add("Hi.");

  Fun(2, abc);

  ...

  void Fun(int i, IList<string> abc) {
    if (abc.Any())
      abc.Add("its me.");
  }

  ...

  Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", abc
    .Select((item, index) => $"{index + 1}){item}")));
```